# How can I access exit polls by state for the 1984 U.S. Presidential Election?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, history, reference-request, exit-polls

Even though the 1984 presidential election was a landslide, and there's a national exit poll available, I want to see if there were any differences in exit polls by state. For example, an exit poll from California compared with an exit poll from Texas. But I'm not sure how or where to access those exit polls. Does anyone know how I can access them, or if anyone here has access to them themselves?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on the 1984 election has [state results](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1984_United_States_presidential_election#Results_by_state) (sourced from [here](https://uselectionatlas.org/RESULTS/data.php?year=1984&datatype=national&def=1&f=0&off=0&elect=0)) if that does anything for you.

Comment: I appreciate your response, but I'm actually looking for exit poll info for each state, or at least some of them.